# cannot use native node module in electron-forge app

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-forge

I am trying to use [pkcs11js](https://github.com/PeculiarVentures/pkcs11js) in an electron app created with electron-forge using webpack template.

But I got the error

```
Error: C:\ws-p\electron-test\.webpack\main\349a63bd9833f80e7879a5bbfb2a4af2.node is not a valid Win32 application.
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:18)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)←[39m
←[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47←[39m
```

There are lots of questions asked around but none of the provided solutions/answers worked for me so far.

None of these worked out:

- remove & reinstall node_modules
- use `electron-rebuild` (although electron-forge uses this internally)
- use `node-gyp rebuild --target=13.1.0 --arch=x64 --dist-url=https://electronjs.org/headers` manually for the package
- Npm steps defined in [electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules#using-npm)

**Environment**:

```
Windows 10 Pro
Node 14.16.1
electron: 13.1.0
electron-rebuild: 2.3.5
electron-forge: 6.0.0-beta.57
pkcs11js: 1.2.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the solutions on the web worked for me. What worked is defining `electron-gyp` output folder as home before `electron-rebuild` or with electron-forge right after/before dependencies install.

In a terminal:

Windows:

```
set HOME=C:\Users\YourUser\.electron-gyp
npm i
npm run start <# which resolves to electron-forge start #>
```

Unix:

```sh
$ export HOME=~/.electron-gyp
$ npm i
$ npm run start # which resolves to  electron-forge start
```

I hope it helps to someone

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Electron Forge [Webpack template](https://www.electronforge.io/config/plugins/webpack#native-modules) which has better support for native modules.

There is currently an [open issue](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/2154) for this functionality caused by the outdated/unmaintained `@marshallofsound/webpack-asset-relocator-loader` which caters for native modules via Webpack. I'm currently working on a [PR](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/pull/2320) to fix this but in the meantime you can use [my updated fork](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@timfish/webpack-asset-relocator-loader).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I already use webpack template and with `@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader`.  I have solved the problem in another way. I will post answer

Comment: The vercel plugin currently only works as expected in the electron main process

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will keep that in mind as for now I only use native modules in main process

Comment: Just be aware that you should not make any blocking calls in the main process as these block communication between renderer processes and the GPU process which can in turn can cause rendering to be "janky".